# Integer as SQL Alias doesn’t error but gives incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, alias

I was working on some SQL code today where the originator had mistaken the Alias of a table, which was the letter l, but they had typed with the number 1.

Even though this error had been made the code still ran.

Here is an example of the code

```
SELECT l.[Name]
       ,l.Address
       ,1.Postcode
FROM List l
```

with the mistake being the code `1.Postcode` instead of `l.Postcode`

The results came out with the Postcode column all 1’s, as below

[image: Incorrect]

If the mistake was to use `t.Postcode` then it would give an error

> The multi-part identifier " t.Postcode " could not be bound.

But instead of erroring `1.Postcode` is being treated as `1 AS Postcode`

Correcting the line to `l.Postcode` gives the correct data, as below

[image: Correct]

So my question is why doesn’t the line `1.Postcode` error?

Comment: Please add a database tag. I repoduced in sql server, intriguing.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, just added the tag. It is weird isn't it.

Comment: I tested in sql server 2014. Yes it is weird.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server is possibly treating as a property of a user defined type?

Comment: Somebody else noticed it, tiny bit of info [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28941695/using-dot-as-an-alias-in-SQL-server.html)

Comment: Good find. This also works: `SELECT 2.0Postcode ` results `2.0`

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger that does help explain.

Comment: @JacobH it also gets 1 if I type `1Postcode`. So it doesn't even need the .

Comment: If you insert into a table, you'll find the datatype of `1.Postcode` is a decimal. If you try without the dot, it'll probably be an int  (im not behind computer anymore, so can't test more)

Comment: @HoneyBadger you are correct `1Postcode` inserted into a table sets it a datatype int. `1.0Postode` gave me datatype numeric(2, 1) on 2008R2

Comment: `'abc'Postcode` gives results of abc. `'abc'.Postcode` fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax `1.Postcode` is treated by sql-server as `+1.0 AS Postcode`

There is a misunderstanding, it throw no errors because there is no error to throw, and it give the right result... for this syntax..

The main problem here is that the space between column value and column alias is not mandatory, and in some circumnstances, can be omitted.

[SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql) From Microsoft docs:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]  
[ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
<select_list>   
<select_list> ::=   
    {   
      *   
      | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*   
      | {  
          [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]  
               { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }   
          | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name }   
            | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]  
          | expression  
          [ [ AS ] column_alias ]   
         }  
      | column_alias = expression   
    } [ ,...n ]
```

As you can see, considering the dot between `1` and `Postcode` as a separator, `1` is not a `table_name, view_name, table_alias, nor a udt_column_name`, so it remains only `method_name` and `expression`.
But `1.Postcode` cannot be a `method_name` ([cannot start with a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers#rules-for-regular-identifiers)), so your case is **`expression [ [ AS ] column_alias ]`**

where:

> *expression*
>   Is a constant, function, any combination of column names, constants, and functions connected by an operator or operators, or a subquery.

Well.. again, `1` cannot be a function nor a colum name ([cannot start with a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers#rules-for-regular-identifiers)), so it **MUST** be a [constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql).

the 1st character `1` is a number different from 0.. so it cannot be nothing else than a `bit, integer, decimal or float constant`, but the 2nd character `.` restricts only to decimal and float constant.

After the `.` we have `P`, it is not a number.. and it is not `E` or `e` (which denotes the float constants) so we have found a decimal constant.

The following is not `AS` (please note the blank after `AS`) so it could be the column alias, and `Postcode` is a valid column alias.. so we have our new column, its value is `1` (precisely `1.0`) and its name is `Postcode`

take a look at these examples and enjoy:

```
select 
    1.Postcode_decimal, -- 1.0 AS Postcode_decimal
    1.ePostcode_float, -- 1.0E0 AS Postcode_float
    1.asPostcode_decimal, -- 1.0 AS asPostcode_decimal
    1.as PostcodeAS_decimal, -- 1.0 AS PostcodeAS_decimal
    1Postcode_int, -- 1 AS Postcode_int
    1.+1.Postcode_expression, -- (1.0 + 1.0) AS Postcode_expression
    1.%1.+1+0.-.0/.1e-1Postcode_more_complex_expr, -- (1.0 % 1.0) + 1 + (0.0 / 0.1E-1) AS Postcode_more_complex_expr
    0xPostcode_varbin, -- 0x00 as Postcode_varbin
    3.5[3.5], -- 3.5 AS [3.5]
    'Hello'Postcode_varchar, 
    '1.0'[1.0], -- value is varchar, name is '1.0'  
    -- you can single quote an alias 
    22'Postcode_int2', 
    22'2.2',
    -- but beware of two single quotes are treated as one literal single quote.. 
    'Hello''Postcode_varchar'_  -- yes, the underscore can be an identifier..
into 
    #test_alias

SELECT * FROM #test_alias

select column_ordinal, name, is_nullable, system_type_name, max_length, precision, source_column
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM #test_alias',null,1) 

drop table #test_alias
```

Outputs:

```
Postcode_decimal    Postcode_float  asPostcode_decimal  PostcodeAS_decimal  Postcode_int    Postcode_expression Postcode_more_complex_expr  Postcode_varbin Postcode_varchar    1.0 Postcode_int2   2.2 _                       3.5
1                   1               1                   1                   1               2                   1                           0x              Hello               1.0 22              22  Hello'Postcode_varchar  3.5
```

and

```
column_ordinal  name                        is_nullable system_type_name    max_length  precision   
1               Postcode_decimal            0           numeric(1,0)        5           1           
2               Postcode_float              0           float               8           53          
3               asPostcode_decimal          0           numeric(1,0)        5           1           
4               PostcodeAS_decimal          0           numeric(1,0)        5           1           
5               Postcode_int                0           int                 4           10          
6               Postcode_expression         1           numeric(2,0)        5           2           
7               Postcode_more_complex_expr  1           float               8           53          
8               Postcode_varbin             0           varbinary(1)        1           0           
9               Postcode_varchar            0           varchar(5)          5           0           
10              1.0                         0           varchar(3)          3           0           
11              Postcode_int2               0           int                 4           10          
12              2.2                         0           int                 4           10          
13              _                           0           varchar(22)         22          0           
14              3.5                         0           numeric(2,1)        5           2
```